# hide android title bar without animations

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to show the title bar of my android app on some layouts but not on others. I navigate between layouts without a problem and I call `getSupportActionBar().hide();` or `getSupportActionBar().show();` without problems, the titlebar does indeed show or hide when I want it to. However, there is an animation which is very ugly and annoying plus it causes some strange graphics problems (black background in my app but it shows a white background in the place of the title bar during its animation)

There is a method for disabling the animation but it does not seem to work at all. How can I have a title bar one one activity but not the other without having an annoying animation to show/hide it? And why cant I just call the method and have it work as it should?

The method I am trying to call is `getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);`

it is worth noting that my app is extremely simple and only has two layouts and one java activity. I just inflate two different layouts to show on my one activity.

How it looks like currently: https://i.imgur.com/djTWokI.mp4

Comment: "causes some strange graphics problems (black background in my app but it shows a white background in the place of the title bar during its animation)" - it sounds like you haven't set your activity's `windowBackground` correctly. You should fix that first.

Comment: Did you look at the gif I linked? Also all colors in themes.xml are set to black and I have no idea where that white in the bottom comes from. It looks like a glitch in my eyes.

Comment: You've haven't included your `themes.xml` in your question, so we can't confirm that you've set your `windowBackground` appropriately - white is the default.

Comment: Alright, I did add a ```<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>``` tag which removed the white so its all black now and it looks a little bit better but the animation is still terribly ugly and makes my image resize during the animation in a choppy way, so showing and hiding the action bar without any animations is still my goal.

Comment: Do you enable the animation in your layout?

Comment: I never enabled anything, its all default settings. I am trying to remove the animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

You can try changing AndroidManifest.xml like this

Comment: android:theme currently links to a file called theme.xml and removing that links breaks all kinds of stuff. Also, setting "NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" in androidmanifest would mean I would get no titlebar in any layout, would it not? Because I want a layout in one page but not the other.

Comment: oh yea, didnt think of that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I sort of solved it myself by creating a custom titlebar which I have full control over. What really frustrated me was that `setShowHideAnimationEnabled(boolean)` doesnt seem to work properly and I couldnt find any official documentation about it.

Googling for it only gave me results from like 2010 about how to enable animations but when animations are enabled by default, I wanted to remove them.

Anyway, turning the actionbar off in the entire application/activity is possible and that is what I did, I then created my own custom actionbar layout and added it to the page(s) that I want to utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

If your context is an activity you can call **overridePendingTransition**:

> Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or
> finish specifying an explicit transition animation to perform next.

So, programmatically:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```